# Removing a parent Node from a flattened json response

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a flattened json response like this :

```
"data.Applicant.Age", "0"
"data.Applicant.IsInsured", "True"
```

i want to be able to remove **data** from the flattened collection using C#.
My Expected result should look like this :

```
"Applicant.Age","0"
"Applicant.IsInsured","True"
```

Comment: Please can you show your JSON object (the above is not JSON). Also, do you mean that you want to take a JSON string, and return a new JSON string starting from `Applicant` instead of `data`?

Comment: yes @John the above response is result of the flattened json

Comment: So you have actually a string, and you want to create another string in JSON format, (including the curly brackets and having keys without the data paret)?
Is what you want to get at last a string?

Comment: After you get the desired output format, what do you plan to do with the new JSON string?

Comment: How about a simple regex replace?

Comment: How about deserializing the JSON then serializing just the bits you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = @"""Applicant.Age"",""0""
""Applicant.IsInsured"",""True""";  // this is a string containing Environment.Newline
var lines = input.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var newLines = new List<string>();
string output;
foreach (var line in lines)
{     
    var key = line.Split(',')[0].Trim();
    var value = line.Split(',')[1].Trim();
    key = key.Substring(6);
    var newLine = string.Join(":", key, value);
    newLines.Add(newLine);
    Console.WriteLine(newLine);
}
```

This code converts your input, which is a string containing two lines, to output, which is a string containing two lines and each line does not have the `data.` part.